# TestCafe assertions over multiple selectors in Promise.allSettled seems misleading

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Consider the following tests:

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'


const validSelector = Selector('html')
const invalidSelector = Selector('non-existent')

//the following test passes and establishes a baseline for the assertions below
test
  ('baseline', async t => {
    await t
      .expect(validSelector.exists).ok()
      .expect(invalidSelector.exists).notOk()
})

//here the first set of assertions pass, while the second fail
test
  ('Promise.allSettled is misleading', async t => {
    let selectors = [validSelector, validSelector, invalidSelector]
    let expected = ['fulfilled', 'fulfilled', 'rejected']
    await Promise.allSettled(selectors.map(async selector => await t.expect(selector.exists).ok()))
      .then(async o => await t.expect(JSON.stringify(o.map(result => result.status)) === JSON.stringify(expected)).ok())

    selectors = [validSelector, invalidSelector, validSelector]
    expected = ['fulfilled', 'rejected', 'fulfilled']
    await Promise.allSettled(selectors.map(async selector => await t.expect(selector.exists).ok()))
      .then(async o => await t.expect(JSON.stringify(o.map(result => result.status)) === JSON.stringify(expected)).ok(JSON.stringify(o.map(result => result.status))))
})


const handleExceptions = async (selector) =>
  await t.expect(selector.exists).ok()
    .then(f => true)
    .catch(r => false)

//here all of the promises are fulfilled due to the exception handling,
//but as one may expect the results are the same as in the previous test -- the assertion at the end fails
test
  ('Promise.allSettled with exception handling is still misleading', async t => {
    const selectors = [validSelector, invalidSelector, validSelector]
    const expected = [true, false, true]
    await Promise.allSettled(selectors.map(async selector => await handleExceptions(selector)))
      .then(async o => await t.expect(JSON.stringify(o) === JSON.stringify(expected)).ok(JSON.stringify(o)))
})

//in this test the assertion actually passes
test
  ('Snapshots seem like the only viable option', async t => {
    const tags = ['html', 'non-existent', 'html']
    const expected = [true, false, true]
    await Promise.allSettled(tags.map(async tag => await Selector(tag)))
      .then(async selectors => await Promise.allSettled(selectors.map(async s => await s.value())))
      .then(snapshots => snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.value != null))
      .then(async o => await t.expect(JSON.stringify(o) === JSON.stringify(expected)).ok(JSON.stringify(o)))
})
```

The question is -- is the described behaviour of Promise.allSettled in the cases above expected due to some perk of TestCafe or the usage above is in any way wrong?

In case it's the former, then should users take the snapshots route as the last test suggests or there are other viable options (maybe safer, faster, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue is related to the following open TestCafe issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5623. Please vote for it and subscribe to notifications to learn about our progress.